# Extract values from a JSON String

Tags: javascript, json

What's the best way to get a clean array from this:

```
[{f=[{v=2521998}, {v=0}, {v=99326}]}]
```

to something like this?

```
[2521998,0,99326]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems not a valid json. And, you just want to get all `v`'s value under `f`? Is there other requirements like if there's `f2`, do you want to put them to the same array?

Comment: You meant this? `[{"f":[{"v":2521998}, {"v":0}, {"v":99326}]}]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you haven't mentioned the `[{f=[{v=2521998}, {v=0}, {v=99326}]}]` is `string` or `array`, I've included both the answers.

**For Array/Object/JSON**

1. Your `json` is not valid(See the correct formatted below)
2. `regex` can be used in your case.

You can convert the `object` to `string` using `JSON.stringify` and then use `regex` to extract the required values from it.

```js
var myArr = [{
  f: [{
    v: 2521998
  }, {
    v: 0
  }, {
    v: 99326
  }]
}];

var str = JSON.stringify(myArr);

var resultArr = str.match(/\d+/g);

alert(resultArr);
```

**String**

If `[{f=[{v=2521998}, {v=0}, {v=99326}]}]` is `string` and not `object/array`, you don't need `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var str = '[{f=[{v=2521998}, {v=0}, {v=99326}]}]';
var resultArr = str.match(/\d+/g);

alert(resultArr);
```

**REGEX Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\d`: Matches any digit
3. `+`: Matches one or more of the preceding class
4. `g`: Global matches.

Comment: why you do `JSON.stringify`, possibly OP mean string instead of plain object?

Comment: @blex, now more people when say JSON mean plain object instead of string :-) so we can only guess what mean OP :-)

Comment: @Grundy, @ blex No worries. I've added both the answers